# scrollable container without putting height

Tags: javascript, css, html

[image: **scrollable container without putting height## Heading ##**]

```
<div class="container">
<header>
    HOME
</header>
<div class="image-responsive">
  <img src="http://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/003366.png">
</div>
<div class="container-scroll">
    <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
</div>
<footer>x y z</footer>
```

i had already tried to make a div scrollable without putting any fix height but its not working properly and there is a image just after the header part that image is responsive according to device.

i want a template like this shown images ,my image is responsive according to the device.
 and the middle part (text container ) should be scrollable without any height.

Comment: giving this in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be more helpful.

Comment: is there a maximum height the image would be before it becomes trashed? This info may help the situation...surely it can't scale in height indefinately and still be presentable to a user? Try a `max-height: ## ;` perhaps and a `height:auto;` in the image call. Also ...this fiddle has no rule defined in the css for the image-container class. Just saying.

Comment: no there is no max-height

Comment: image is randomly came form server and i can't put any max or min height.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate (javascript) the remaining available height like this:

```
var yourScrollableDivsHeight = windowHeight - stickyHeaderHeight - stickyFooterHeight - dynamicImageHeight;
```

Once you get to this number, you can give it as a fixed height to the scrollable Div, and apply `overflow-y:auto;` to it.